# Node-red swagger api node

Tags: node-red

I am trying to use 'node-red-contrib-swagger node' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-swagger) to create a simple web service by reading my swagger api but unable to do so.  I have added simple http in, swagger node and http response to send back the response given by my swagger api, but its not working.

How do I call this node red api and successfully get some response?  I tried by calling 127.0.0.1:1880/nodeSwaggger?thing=test from browser after deploying the below flow but in debug screen it says 'No response object'.  Below is the node-red flow JSON, any idea/help would be appreciated.

[{"id":"3c3cdbac.7eb984","type":"http in","z":"6c4b5e4.a5914a","name":"Swagger API","url":"/nodeSwaggger","method":"get","swaggerDoc":"","x":133,"y":107,"wires":[["a012d9db.a5c558"]]},{"id":"a012d9db.a5c558","type":"swagger api","z":"6c4b5e4.a5914a","api":"https://dweet.io/play/definition","resource":"dweets","method":"getAllDweets","intype":"","outtype":"","authconfig":"","name":"test","x":209.5,"y":237,"wires":[["a85c4d8a.8d5b7"]]},{"id":"a85c4d8a.8d5b7","type":"http response","z":"6c4b5e4.a5914a","name":"","x":438,"y":109,"wires":[]}]

Thanks in advance,
Manju

Comment: The "flow" you exported there only contains the swagger node, can you edit the question to include the http-in and http-response node on either side as well so we can see the full set up

Comment: Hi hardillb, thanks for your obversation, I have now added the full flow as well, regards.